# How to parse string data to string and long?

Tags: c#

I need from this "fuel_con_ins":0.220500007272 to get 0.220500007272. Can't figure it out myself and i am not able to find any info online

```
int c = b.Split(':').Length - 1;
string resultString = Regex.Match(b.Split(':')[c], @"\d+").Value;

try  
{                                   
    Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(resultString));
}
```

I need from this "fuel_con_ins":1.220500007272 to get 1.220500007272, but for now the output is 1.

Comment: Either use `Split` or `regex`, there is no need for both

Answer (score 3):

The `"\d+"` regex pattern doesn't include the decimal dot, that's why you are getting `1` (the regex stops at the dot, so you are only getting the integral part here)

You don't really need a regex here... just the split would suffice:

```
var myFloat = float.Parse(myString.Split(':')[1])
```

As an additional note (not related to the question), do not use a `try {} catch` block for doing parsings unless you expect the failing to be an actual exception... for normal usage, you should use `float.TryParse()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can also find first char which IsDigit and create a Substring.
But the easiest way is to use Split if you have ':' always.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) since the precision of [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) is only 6-9 digits.
Keep in mind that you might have to use `,` instead of `.` when working with double.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
 Regex.Split(sentence, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "")
```